# How to start a node express application in a different host than localhost

Tags: node.js, express, networking, cloud, host

How to start a node express application in a different host than localhost?
I want to start my node application in different host than localhost on my laptop itself. (I want to emulate two applications communicating with each other which are in two different data centers. So I'm starting one application in localhost and another in some other host)

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the localhost port?

Comment: I want to change the host to something like 10.10.0.1. not just the port. (10.10.0.1 is a private address)